# Java 8 Looping Special Pyramid Logic

Tags: java, loops, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(640,480,520,170,320,140,60);`
And I need to find sum for given elements as per below iteration logic.
For example first Outer Iteration like 640+480, Then 640+480+520 and so on till 60.

Next iteration starts from 480+520 , then 480+520 +170 and so on.

The sample Java 7 Program is like

```
List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(640,480,520,170,320,140,60);
        List<Integer> newListWithSum=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int mainIndex=0;mainIndex<list.size();mainIndex++) {
            for(int index=mainIndex;index<list.size();index++) {
                int sum=0;
                for(int nestedIndex=mainIndex;nestedIndex<index+1;nestedIndex++) {
                    sum=sum+list.get(nestedIndex);
                }
                newListWithSum.add(sum);
            }
        }
```

but I need to change above logic to Java 8 version. Please help/share hint to write a simplified Java 8 Logic for sum as per below iteration

[image]

Comment: Yes, Java 7 logic is listed above. I need to migrate it to Java 8.

Comment: U need to "migrate" it to java-8?

Comment: I mean for better version, i need to change it to Java 8 (if Stream/IntStream) are better option here?

Comment: nope, what you have is pretty good already. java-8 will not improve the speed/readability nor anything else in this case

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is much more similar to algorithm, let's go step by step

1) First get all the sublists by excluding first integer in each iteration

```
List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(640,480,520,170,320,140,60);

    List<List<Integer>> re = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                                      .mapToObj(sb->list.subList(sb, list.size()))
                                      .filter(s->s.size()>1)
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    re.forEach(ls->System.out.println(ls));
```

**Output**

```
[640, 480, 520, 170, 320, 140, 60]
[480, 520, 170, 320, 140, 60]
[520, 170, 320, 140, 60]
[170, 320, 140, 60]
[320, 140, 60]
[140, 60]
```

2) Now on each list do the sum

```
List<List<Integer>> re1 = re.stream()
                            .map(j->IntStream.rangeClosed(2, j.size()).mapToObj(sl->j.stream().limit(sl).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

 re1.forEach(ls->System.out.println(ls));
```

**Output**

```
[1120, 1640, 1810, 2130, 2270, 2330]
[1000, 1170, 1490, 1630, 1690]
[690, 1010, 1150, 1210]
[490, 630, 690]
[460, 520]
[200]
```

**Combined solution of step 1 and step 2**

```
List<List<Integer>> re = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                                      .mapToObj(sb->list.subList(sb, list.size()))
                                      .filter(s->s.size()>1)
                                      .map(j->IntStream.rangeClosed(2, j.size()).mapToObj(sl->j.stream().limit(sl).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to transform the code you have you can use the following snippet:

```
List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i,  list.size()))
        .flatMap(l -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, l.size()).mapToObj(i -> l.subList(0, i).stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This creates an `Intstream` from `0` to `n - 1` and maps all the lists which the items should be summed up. These lists are mapped again to the actual items to calculate the sum. This is on in the `reduce` step. At the end all streams are flattened an finaly collected to the result list:

```
[640, 1120, 1640, 1810, 2130, 2270, 2330, 480, 1000, 1170, 1490, 1630, 1690, 520, 690, 1010, 1150, 1210, 170, 490, 630, 690, 320, 460, 520, 140, 200, 60]
```